# Running a function as soon as a the 1st of the month comes without a 3rd party library in javascript (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, setinterval

I would like to make a function run (create a document in my mongodb with mongoose, but this doesn't really matter) every 1st of a new month, preferably as soon as the date changes.

What I want to do is to have a analitics of a full month. The code already searches for a document with an id of the year/month. I just want to automate the process of the document creation.

I don't want to use a 3rd party lib like needle or cronjob, can we do this only with setInterval and setTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
function runOnNextMonth(fn) {
  const first = new Date;
  first.setMonth(first.getMonth() + 1);
  first.setDate(1);
  first.setHours(0);
  first.setMinutes(0);
  first.setSeconds(1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    fn();
    runOnNextMonth(fn);
  }, first.getTime() - Date.now());
}
```